# iText Document get URL

Tags: java, pdf, url, itext

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));

document.open();
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello World", font);

document.add(chunk);
document.close();
```

This generates `test.pdf` on root folder of my project. Now I need a `java.net.URL` of that file. How can I get that?

Comment: What keeps you from generating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this could work:

```
File output_file = new File("test.pdf");

//Change Line 2 to:
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(output_file));

//To get the java.net.URL
URL url = output_file.toURI().toURL();
```